# How to communicate from React Native in Android with a USB device?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I need to establish communication with a USB device, but I'm encountering issues with finding a reliable React Native library for this purpose. Currently, I am trying 'react-native-usb-serialport-for-android', but I'm facing difficulties. I'm sharing a code snippet along with the error message I'm encountering, in the hopes that someone might know how to resolve it. Additionally, I'm open to suggestions for other libraries that are known to work well.

```js
import {
  UsbSerialManager,
  UsbSerial,
  Parity,
} from 'react-native-usb-serialport-for-android'
import {Alert} from 'react-native'

/**
 * Requests USB permission and opens a USB serial port.
 * @returns {Promise<null>} A promise that resolves to null.
 */
export async function requestUSBPermission(): Promise<null> {
  try {
    // Get a list of available USB devices
    const devices = await UsbSerialManager.list();

    // Try to request permission for the first device in the list
    const granted = await UsbSerialManager.tryRequestPermission(
      devices[0].deviceId
    );

    if (granted) {
      // Open a USB serial port with the specified configuration
      const usbSerialport = await UsbSerialManager.open(devices[0].deviceId, {
        baudRate: 9600,
        parity: Parity.None,
        dataBits: 8,
        stopBits: 1
      });

      // TODO: Add code to interact with the USB serial port

    } else {
      // Show an alert indicating that USB permission was denied
      Alert.alert('USB permission denied');
      return null;
    }

    return null;
  } catch (err) {
    // Log any errors that occur during USB permission request or port opening
    console.error(err);
    return null;
  }
}
```

But when I execute the function, I get the following error:

[Screnshoot error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nt0Kc.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

update your sdk version in build.gradle inside node modules of react-native-usb-serialport-for-android  like this
-- Path to file => ''node_modules\react-native-usb-serialport-for-android\android\build.gradle''

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion safeExtGet('UsbSerialportForAndroid_compileSdkVersion', 33)
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion safeExtGet('UsbSerialportForAndroid_minSdkVersion', 23)
        targetSdkVersion safeExtGet('UsbSerialportForAndroid_targetSdkVersion', 33)
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'GradleCompatible'
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).